# Disk space issue in AWS EMR Cluster

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, yum, emr, amazon-emr

We have provisioned 11 nodes(1 master + 10 cores) EMR cluster in AWS. We have chosen disk space for each node as 100 GB.

When the cluster is provisioned, the EMR automatically allocated only 10GB to root partition(/dev/xvda1). After some days root partition disk space becomes full, due to this we couldn't run any job or install basic softwares like git using yum command.

```
[hadoop@<<ip address>> ~]$ df -BG
Filesystem     1G-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs             79G    1G       79G   1% /dev
tmpfs                79G    0G       79G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1           10G    10G       0G  100% /
/dev/xvdb1            5G    1G        5G   4% /emr
/dev/xvdb2           95G   12G       84G  12% /mnt
/dev/xvdf            99G   12G       83G  12% /data
```

Could you please help us, how to resolve this issue?

1. How to increase root partition(/dev/xvda1) disk space to 30GB?
2. By default all installation using yum or rpm goes to root partition(/dev/xvda1). How to by-pass softwares installing to root partition(/dev/xvda1)?
3. Whatever the solution, it should not disturb the existing EMR installation.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your configuration? What instance type are you using for the Core Nodes? Have you added any additional EBS space to the core nodes?

Comment: Instance type of core node is m4.10xlarge(80 vCPU, 160GiB memory, EBS only storage EBS Storage: 100 GiB). We didn't add any additional EBS space.

Answer (score 2):

Recently ran into same issue. Find the corresponding ec2 instance and in description tab find and click on the link root device. It points to a EBS Id, click on it. In the actions click on modify volume. After requesting required total space. you might have to aditionally run commands such as "growpart" to let the os adjust to the new size.

Answer (score 0):

All EMR AMI's come with fixed root volume of 10GB and so will be all ec2 instances of your EMR cluster.  All applications that you select on EMR will be installed on this root volume and are expected to take about 90% of this disk. At this moment, neither increasing this volume size nor application installation behavior can be altered. So, you should refrain from using this root volume to install application and rather install your custom apps on bigger volumes like /mnt/. You can also symlink some root directories to bigger volumes and then install your apps.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed information. I have few more clarification, 1. how to bypass installation of softwares to root partition while using "yum" commands? 2. how to create symlink on some root directories to bigger volumes? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `/var/aws/emr/packages` takes most of the space (30%). Idk if this folder can be `rm -rf /var/aws/emr/packages`'d or should be symlinked to `/mnt`, but removing it seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

EBS root volume size can also be increased while at the time of launching the EMR cluster. Default is 10GB


Once the EMR is up and running, then also we can increase the root volume. Refer to this AWS blog -> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-volume-size-increase/